# Equivalent definitions of Markov process, existence of transition function and initial distributions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I found two diffent ways to define Markov processes. It can be defined with a transition function and a collection of probability measures or just by the Markov property. I want to understand the connection between these two possibilities. To be precise I have the following problem:

Let $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},\mathbb {P} )$ be a probability space with a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t,\ t \in T)$, for some (totally ordered) index set  $T$; and let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be a measure space. Let an $E$-valued stochastic process $X=(X_t,\ t\in T)$ be adapted to the filtration, such that  for each $s,t\in T$ with $s < t$ and every $f:E\to E$ measurable and bounded,
$$
\mathbb{E}(f(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_s)=\mathbb{E}(f(X_t)|\sigma(X_s)).
$$
Then I want to prove the following:

There exists a transition function $(P_t)_t$ ($P_t:E\times\mathcal{E}\to[0,1]$), such that for every distribution $\nu$ on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ there exists a probability distribution $\mathbb{P}_\nu$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ with 
$$ 
(i)\quad \mathbb{P}_\nu(X_0\in B)=\nu(B)\text{ for every }B\in\mathcal{E}
$$
$$
(ii)\quad \mathbb{E}_\nu(f(X_{t+s})|\mathcal{F}_s)=P_tf(X_s)=\mathbb{E}_{X_s}f(X_t),\quad \mathbb{P}_\nu-\text{a.s.}
$$
where $\mathbb{E}_\nu$ is the expectation induced by $\mathbb{P}_\nu$ and
$$
\mathbb{E}_{X_s}f(X_t):\Omega\to\mathbb{R},\quad\omega\mapsto \mathbb{E}_{X_s(\omega)}f(X_t)
$$
and furthermore $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{P}_{\delta_0}$.

Can someone tell me how to find/construct suitable transition kernels $P_t$ and probability distributions $\mathbb{P}_\nu$? Is there some kind of uniqunes in these choices?

Comment: By definition of conditional expectations, $E(f(X_t)\mid X_s)=g(X_s)$ and the mapping $f\mapsto g$ is linear. Your transition semi-group is then $P_{s,t}f=g$.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Do you also know how we get the $\mathbb{P}_\nu$?

Comment: This is just a notation to specify that the initial distribution is $\nu$.

Comment: Do you think the claim above is not correct? Is it not true that for every $\nu$ exists a probability measure $\mathbb{P}_\nu$ with the above properties?

Comment: ?? Where would I have said / hinted / whatever, that the claim does not hold?

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. I don't mean $\mathbb{P}_\nu$ in just a notational sense. I really want to construct or prove the existence of actual probability measures $\mathbb{P}_\nu$ on the space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ with the above mentioned properties. Probably the answer is very trivial but it would help me a lot for my understanding.

Comment: Every finite dimensional marginal is uniquely specified by these conditions, and they are compatible by projections, hence [Kolmogorov extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) ensures the existence and uniqueness of a probability measure with these marginals on the corresponding cylinder sigma-algebra.

Comment: Could you explain your sketch of a possible proof of the exstence of the $\mathbb{P}_\nu$ more detailed? I would be very glad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55069/discussion-between-drogan-and-did).